# Cross-platform validation issues: links not working on some devices

Tags: magento, testing, cross-browser, cross-platform, error-reporting

I have a magento site, and a menu on it. They menu isn't super complicated. Here is a snippet of the menu:

```
<ul class="nav top-main-navigation">
<li class="dropdown"><a href="/jewelry-categories.html">Jewelry</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <div class="jewelry">
<li><a href="/jewelry-categories/pendants.html">Pendants</a></li>
etc ...
```

However, I've noticed that on samsung devices the links won't redirect to the page they are suppose too. It works on desktop on multiple browsers and Iphones, and other android phones. What can I do to fix this intermittent issue?

Edit:
The phone I'm having issues with is a Galaxy s8

Comment: Do you have a link and specify the Samsung Device you are using?

Comment: i edited the question to have the phone in it, im not sure if i am suppose to post the site (it's a company not a personal site)

Comment: what is the name of the company site then? Describe it well enough so that I can find it (name, location - or perhaps past domain with tld - not the link but just the domain)